# VSCode typescript autosuggestion broken after migration to pnpm

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, pnpm

### Setup

We have a monorepo and recently we decided to migrate from yarn to pnpm.

Node version: 14.20.0
pnpm version: 7.9.5
Typescript version: 4.4.2

After migrating to pnpm I updated the package manager settings in VSCode as below:

[image: VSCode package manager setting]
[image: ESLint package manager setting]

### Problem

*(The problem described below occurs in more that 1 apps, but for the sake of simplicity I will focus on one)*

In one of the monorepo's apps we use React with TypeScript.

The problem is that **VSCode does not seem to read the nested dependencies' types.**

### Example

One of the app's dependencies (specified in its package.json) is `react-router-dom` and `react-router-dom` has `react-router` as a dependency.

`react-router-dom` exports the `useLocation` hook from `react-router`.

When I use the `useLocation` hook, VSCode displays its type as

[image]

ESLint does not display any error, so it seems that it is able to follow pnpm's symlinks and read `useNavigate` hook's type.

Why isn't VSCode able to properly read the nested dependency's types?

##### *Edits*

VSCode typescript version used
[image]

Comment: Sounds like you need to use the specific typescript version provided by pnpm so TS can infer the types correctly.

Comment: @Terry It seems I am using the proper ts version (I have updated the description to include screenshot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had some settings in the monorepo's app's `tsconfig` wrong.

To work properly, I had to update it:

##### *From*

[image]

##### *To*

[image]